# How to select exact related values in join table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a problem doing the following `SELECT` statement: I want to select only `articles` that are exactly related to some given `tags`.

Here is my (simplified) schema:

[image]

And here are the (simplified) datas:

[image]

I want to select only `articles` related to `tags` **89** `AND` **137**.
That should return only `article (ID 3)` which is only related to `tags` ID **89** and **137**.

I was thinking about doing this with two queries, but maybe one of you can tell me how to do it in only one.

Thks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came with another solution, which does less subrequests:

```
SELECT at1.article_id
FROM article_tag at1
INNER JOIN article_tag at2
ON at1.article_id = at2.article_id
WHERE at1.tag_id = 89
AND at2.tag_id = 137
AND not exists (
    SELECT *
    FROM article_tag at3
    WHERE at3.article_id = at1.article_id
    AND at3.tag_id != 137
    AND at3.tag_id != 89
)
```

Thank you @Bryan Newman and @Nick for your inspiration.

Answer (score 2):

As I understand it you want to select article ids which relate ONLY to tags 89 **and** 137 and no others? So ID 3 in your sample data, but not ID 4 and 5 (which only relate to one of them) or 6 (which relates to both of them, but also other tags). You can achieve that with this query:

```
select a1.article_id 
from article_tag a1 
where a1.tag_id = 89 and 
    exists (select * from article_tag a2 where a2.article_id = a1.article_id and a2.tag_id = 137) and 
    not exists (select * from article_tag a3 where a3.article_id = a1.article_id and a3.tag_id != 137 and a3.tag_id != 89)
```

Comment: my answer is really similar to yours, sorry i didn't see it.

Answer (score 1):

```
select id as article_id
from article a
where exists
 (select 1
  from article_tag b
  where b.article_id = a.id
  and b.tag_id = 89)
and exists
 (select 1
  from article_tag c
  where c.article_id = a.id
  and c.tag_id = 137)
and not exists
  (select 1
  from article_tag d
  where d.article_id = a.id
  and d.tag_id not in (89,137))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way, assuming no duplicates in `article_tag`:

```
select article_id
from article_tag
group by article_id
having count(*) = sum( tag_id in (89, 137) );
```

This does exactly what you want.  The `sum()` can return 0 (if the tags are not in the article), 1 (if one is), or 2 (if both are).  The `count(*)` is saying that these matches are the only tags for the article.

Comment: Wouldn't this return all article_ids which have 2 tags?

Comment: This isn't what's wanted in this instance

Comment: This won't work as is as it will also return 4 and 5 which have only one tag_id which is in the set (89, 137) i.e. both count(*) and sum(tag_id in (89,137)) will be 1.

Comment: Previous comment was according to my understanding of the question.

Comment: @clinomaniac . . . No.  The expression `sum( tag_id in (89, 137) )` would return 0 (for instance) if the article had neither tag.